# Configure Serilog in CreateHostBuilder method using several appsettings files

Tags: .net-core, serilog, appsettings

To cofigure serilog I modified main function, adding all needed config:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ConfigLogger();
    CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}

private static void ConfigLogger()
{
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(config).CreateLogger();
}
```

At this point it works fine. The issue is that I have two different appsettings files, one for production and another for development.

My first thought was using `#if DEBUG` directive around AddJsonFile line. Then I read I could avoid this directives by making configuration at CreateHostBuilder method, and removing all my ConfigLogger. Modified CreateHostBuilder method:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseSerilog((ctx, logConfig) => logConfig.ReadFrom.Configuration(ctx.Configuration))
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
    });
```

This should be working but I get an exception with an unclear message, but realted to DependencyInjection as I see in the stacktrace. Exception mesage:

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. (Invalid
> URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.)

Application gets closed showing an MessageBox: "There is no process associated with this object".

EDIT:
If I remove all settings related to serilog from appsettings.json file, it loads well. When I have all settings in both files, appsettings.json and appsettings.development.json it tries to read both files and fail, giving me an exception.

Comment: Why juts don't use `AddJsonFile` one more time for another file? Settings will be overwritten

Comment: appsettings files are different for development and production. e.g., connection strings are not the same. About serilog, I'm using seq but just for production, so I don't set this for development. How could I add two files and use only the one I want.